# How to use opencv 'superres' package on Python cv2?

Tags: python, opencv

A simple enough question - I can't seem to find how to import or use `superres` from `cv2` on Python, even though it is documented:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/superres/doc/super_resolution.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I guess there is no official Python API support for the superres module, However you may get some Open Source implementations of the same algorithm from: [SeRanet Github](https://github.com/corochann/SeRanet) or Python [superresolution module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/superresolution/)